# Can a Python script use tablet/pen information?

Tags: python, scripting

Is it possible to use graphic tablet pressure/tilt information in a python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  See [The Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Event.html) for details, but basically there's a structure you can read that has pressure and tilt values that is returned by the event handler.